# Intercept CRUD operations in Couchbase-lite

Tags: java, couchbase-lite

I have to perform some checks before Couchbase-lite Documents are returned to the caller.

```
For Example:

Document doc = database.getExistingDocument(docId);
doc.putProperties(props);
```

What I want is to access the returned Document before it is assigned to "doc", and also intercept "props" before the new revision is committed to storage. May be with the help of something like "BeforeGetListener" and "BeforePutListener", since I have lots of gets and puts.

Is there a way to intercept the CRUD Operations in Couchbase-lite?

Comment: You can construct an wrapper that emit a signal with JSON object of your doc before committed to storage.

Comment: Can you show me a code sample?

Comment: Is just an architectural suggestion.

Comment: Ok. I though about that initially, but I'm still having issues with the implementation. I just hope that there will be a Couchbase-lite API that I missed.

Comment: What do you mean by "access the returned Document before it is assigned to doc".  That doesn't really make sense to me from a programming language perspective.  The second thing you mentioned seems to be validation which is something that is possible if you assign a [validation function](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/references/couchbase-lite/couchbase-lite/database/database/index.html#void-setvalidationstring-name-validatedelegate-delegate) to your database.